# Problems with 'floating' UL

Tags: css

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 110px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.menu li ul {
    display: none;
    max-width: 110px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    list-style: none !important;
    list-style-image: none !important;
}
.menu li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 88, 153, 0.8);
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 9px;
    list-style: none !important;
    list-style-image: none !important;
}
.menu li:hover ul a {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 88, 153, 0.8);
    width: 110px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
```

Above here the code I'm currently using, I want the UL to float above everything, I tried 'fixed' and 'absolute' but then it disappears, I tried to change 'margin-left' to 'inherit' but that didn't work either. I want the UL to float beneath the parent LI.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8PxU/1/)

Comment: Please post a complete code example. Also, a jsFiddle.net example might be useful.

Comment: Complete JSfiddle with HTML & CSS please.

Comment: You might just need to increase the [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). It's unclear, though, if you're using `float` in [the usual CSS meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) -- you say you want it to "float above everything" but then that it should "float beneath the parent LI".

Comment: @Blazemonger Increasing the z-index doesn't work ;S And if you look at the JSfiddle it might not be so unclear, I want it to float at the same place as it is now, but without moving text etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/digiman07/DnEL8/ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the submenu absolutely after first having positioned the parent `li` relative

**HTML (Corrected)** (with thanks to @Malcom for the container

```
<div class="container">
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
As you can see, this text moves when you hover 'Sub'
```

CSS (clipped to relevant parts)

```
.menu li {
    float: left;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative; /* this */
}

.menu li ul {
    position: absolute; /* this */
    display: none;
    max-width: 110px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    list-style: none !important;

list-style-image: none !important;
```

}

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DnEL8/6/)

Comment: Well, it works, but not really the way I want, when I want to hover the sub-items they disappear before I can hover them, how to fix?

Comment: Thar was because of the 9px margin you had in there on the submenu `ul` - http://jsfiddle.net/DnEL8/14/